# Difference between mercurial commands pull -b <branchname> vs pull -r <branchname>

Tags: mercurial

What's the difference between following mercurial commands

`pull -b <branchname>` **vs** `pull -r <branchname>`

I searched alot but I got mixed results and none of them were clear.

Can anyone explain the difference and and scenarios where one should use one above the other ?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
pull -b <branchname>
```

Specifically says "branch <branchname>".

This:

```
pull -r <branchname>
```

Specifically says "revision that matches <branchname>".

The two will differ only when the name of the branch could mean different things as well. For instance, this is entirely legal:

```
hg branch 21e34fb985bb
```

However, if that is also an identifying hash of a changeset, this command is now a bit ambiguous:

```
hg pull -r 21e34fb985bb
```

Did you mean the branch with that name, or the changeset with that hash?

Using `-b <branchname>` uses the branch, the other one, unsure.

Will it matter? Most likely not, and if it would I would urge you to pick a different naming convention for your branches.

Comment: Does it make a difference between what branch you are on ?

Answer (score 1):

In `hg pull --branch branchname`, `branchname` refers to the branch named `branchname`.

In `hg pull --rev branchname`, `branchname` is interpreted as a *revision*, and it refers to the revision that is the latest head of the branch `branchname` in the remote repo. This is mentioned in the [NamedBranches documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches#Merge_Branches):

> Branch names can be used anywhere that tag names can, including log,
>   diff, push, and pull. When a branch has multiple heads, the tipmost
>   revision of the branch will be found.

The two commands might have a different result if the branch `branchname` has more than one head in the remote repo.

Consider the following scenario:

```
o  f
|
o  e
|
| o  d
| |
| o  c
|/
o  b          o  b
|             |
o  a          o  a

remote        local
```

Suppose that the changesets `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` are all in branch `default`.

If you `hg pull --rev default`, `default` is interpreted as a *revision* and it is referring to the latest head of the branch `default` in the remote repo; of the two head revisions `d` and `f`, the latest is `f` (it was probably pushed into the remote repo more recently than `d` was), so your command will be equivalent to `hg pull --rev f`. This will pull into your repo revision `f` and all its ancestors, i.e. revisions `a`, `b`, `e`, `f`. Since revisions `a`, `b` are already in your local repo, in effect you will be pulling `e`, `f`.

On the other hand `hg pull --branch default` will pull into your repo all the revisions in branch `default`, i.e. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`. Since `a`, `b` are already in your repo, in effect you will be pulling `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`.

#### TL;DR

In summary, one could say that `hg pull --branch branchname` pulls into the local repo all the heads of branch `branchname` in the remote repo (plus all their ancestor changesets, minus the changesets that you already have in your local repo), wheras `hg pull --rev branchname` pulls just the *latest* head of the branch `branchname` in the remote repo (plus all its ancestor changesets, minus the changesets that you already have in your local repo). So if you’re using the standard single-head-per-named-branch workflow, the latest head will always be the *only* head, and therefore as far as you’re concerned the two commands are equivalent.